# Why don't shared posts resolve into post titles?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, title, sharing

Questions can be linked to in one of two ways. One of them keeps track of who "created" the link and the other does not. I.e.

> http://stackoverflow.com/a/14305875/569976
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/14305875/569976
>
> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304234/phpseclib-or-ssh2-pecl-extension/14305875#14305875
>   [phpseclib or ssh2 pecl extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304234/phpseclib-or-ssh2-pecl-extension/14305875#14305875)

The latter gets converted to the post title, but the former doesn't.
Seems to me like it ought to?

And it's not extracting the title from the URL either - I tried changing the "pretty" text in the URL up and it still displayed the original title:

> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304234/xxx/14305875#14305875
>   [phpseclib or ssh2 pecl extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304234/xxx/14305875#14305875)

Comment: Also, fixing that might be a little easier if [the API was modified](http://stackapps.com/questions/3819/allow-post-type-to-optionally-return-title-field) (the problem being that the answer short link is the only one that has to be special-cased, because it doesn't include the question ID), but I'm not sure (it'd certainly help my comment link conversion script). `</shameless self-promotion>`